# Looking for a more effective and efficient way of working with large recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've created a public function in Access.  My goal is if the next business day is a holiday I'm calculating one extra day of interest for payoff purposes.  Below is the working code I have.  The issue I'm haveing is I'm dealing with over 35000 records and the time it takes to run the query is too long.  If there is a better way of do this I will definitely give it a try.  Thanks!

```
Public Function HolidayInterest(Perdiem As Currency) As Currency
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset

Select Case DatePart("w", Date)
    Case 6
        NextBusDay = Date + 3
    Case 7
        NextBusDay = Date + 2
    Case Else
        NextBusDay = Date + 1
End Select

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_Holidays", dbOpenDynaset)

If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
Do While Not rst.EOF
    If rst("HolidayDate") = NextBusDay Then
            HolidayInterest = Perdiem
    Else
            HolidayInterest = 0
    End If
rst.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    'MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

'MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rst.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rst = Nothing 'Clean up
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: For clarification, you are calling this function via some type of query? Also, how long does it take that query to run? So for 35,000 records you call this function and you open the tbl_Holidays 35,000 times?  How many records in tbl_Holidays?  You may be better off loading tbl_Holidays into an array so that it is only opened once.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm calling this fuction in an action query (make table).  I'm not exactly sure how long it takes, more than a half an hour (I Ctrl Break.....after that time). The code does work because I've limited the records when testing.  Could you give me an example of how I would load tbl_holidays into an array.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to avoid the opening the Holiday table 35,000 times. It will load all dates into an Array (only once), then use that array for comparing. But I am curious if your existing process ever worked correctly 100% of the time -- if that table contained more than one holiday? Specifically, when you read the holiday table (regardless of the sort order), then in your loop "If rst("HolidayDate") = NextBusDay Then", since you don't exit the loop if you get a match, your subroutine should always return the results of what happens when checking the last date in the table? Also I didn't find a Dim for NextBusDay, so I added it.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public blnSetArray  As Boolean
Public dHolidays()  As Date
Public iHolidays    As Integer

Public Function HolidayInterest(Perdiem As Currency) As Currency
Dim db  As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim i   As Integer
Dim iLoop   As Integer
Dim NextBusDay  As Date

    ' Save an array of dates the first time
    If blnSetArray = False Then
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_Holidays", dbOpenDynaset)
        i = 0
        If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
            rst.MoveLast
            rst.MoveFirst
            iHolidays = rst.RecordCount
            ReDim dHolidays(rst.RecordCount)
            Do While Not rst.EOF
                i = i + 1
                dHolidays(i) = rst("HolidayDate")
                rst.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        blnSetArray = True
        rst.Close 'Close the recordset
        Set rst = Nothing 'Clean up
        db.Close
        Set db = Nothing
    End If

    Select Case DatePart("w", Date)
        Case 6
            NextBusDay = Date + 3
        Case 7
            NextBusDay = Date + 2
        Case Else
            NextBusDay = Date + 1
    End Select

    HolidayInterest = 0     ' Set as default

    If iHolidays > 0 Then
        For iLoop = 1 To iHolidays
            If dHolidays(iLoop) = NextBusDay Then
                HolidayInterest = Perdiem
                Exit For        ' No need to stay in loop
            End If
        Next iLoop
    Else
        'MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
    End If

'MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

End Function
Function MyTest()
    blnSetArray = False
    Debug.Print HolidayInterest(100#)

End Function
```

Comment: After testing this solution worked.  Do you know how to clear the array after the query has been run.  I only ask because when testing if I added a date to the Holiday table and didn't close and open the database it wouldn't recognize the date added.

Comment: Wherever your VBA code is to run the process, just BEFORE you run your process. add the following line (it will force a rebuild of the Array):  blnSetArray = False    Also, just curious how long the process runs for now?

Comment: Only a few seconds. It's night and day. I appreciate your effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `Perdiem` value you pass as an argument to your function, the only thing that will affect the return value of your function is the current system date as returned by `Date`. In other words, on any given day your function will always return either the `Perdiem` value or zero.

Therefore, we can use a `Static` variable named `TheDateToday` to hold the current date and you will only have to hit the [tbl_Holidays] table once on any given day:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function HolidayInterest(Perdiem As Currency) As Currency
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim NextBusDay As Date
    Static TheDateToday As Date, NextBusDayIsHoliday As Boolean

    If CLng(TheDateToday) <> CLng(Date) Then
        TheDateToday = Date
        Select Case DatePart("w", TheDateToday)
            Case 6
                NextBusDay = DateAdd("d", 3, TheDateToday)
            Case 7
                NextBusDay = DateAdd("d", 2, TheDateToday)
            Case Else
                NextBusDay = DateAdd("d", 1, TheDateToday)
        End Select

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", _
                "PARAMETERS prmDate DateTime;" & _
                "SELECT * FROM tbl_Holidays WHERE HolidayDate=[prmDate]")
        qdf!prmDate = NextBusDay
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

        NextBusDayIsHoliday = Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF)

        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set qdf = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
    End If

    If NextBusDayIsHoliday Then
        HolidayInterest = Perdiem
    Else
        HolidayInterest = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This solution also worked.  I had the same issue as the solution above in that if I added a date to the holiday table it wouldn't recognize the added date unless I closed and open the database or compacted.  This really isn't an issue at all since I add all the holidays for the year at once anyways.